# Forecasting Peak/Global Maximum from Raw Data

Tags: r, forecasting, calculus

I'm trying to see what methods there are to predict when the data will peak based on raw values, along with how to accomplish it in R. Here's what you can assume...

1. The data has a start and end point.
2. The shape of the data when graphed will look like a unimodal distribution.

I know one way to do this is to fit a cubic function and find the peak off predicted values, but this only works well sometimes. Here's an example of it not doing so great.

```
### What the data would look like over the long-run ###

xFull = c(1:15)
yFull = c(4100, 4940, 6600, 8160, 9180, 9500, 9610, 9220, 8610, 
          7490, 6070, 4690, 3690, 3250, 2980)

### What the data is currently ###

x = xFull[1:5]
y = yFull[1:5]
 
fit = lm(y ~ poly(x, 3))
summary(fit)
pred = predict(fit, newdata = list(x = c(1:15)))
plot(c(pred), type = 'b')
pred

1           2           3           4           5           6 
   4093.143    4967.429    6558.857    8187.429    9173.143    8836.000 
          7           8           9          10          11          12 
   6496.000    1473.143   -6912.571  -19341.143  -36492.571  -59046.857 
         13          14          15 
 -87684.000 -123084.000 -165926.857
```

As you can see, the predicted values suggest the peak will be x = 5, but really it should be x = 7 and they seem to drop heavily after the predicted peak.

Is there a better way to do this? As more food for thought, I know this is similar to a trajectory problem in a basic physics course, however those problems assume a constant acceleration of -9.8 m/s^2. In my case, to solve in a similar manner, I would need to allow "acceleration" to vary because the data trend could be increasing at an increasing rate before it peaks. I don't know how to go about solving this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit the comment to specify where I have not limited the question to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.